# Swipe Right or Left

Tags: android, android-fragments, ontouchlistener, swipe-gesture

I tried a lot of different ways to implement swipe left and swipe right, none of them work for me. 
I wanted two fragments to change places by swiping. I tried onFling and onTouch methods copied from here and other sources however either application did not respond to touch or it crashed. I write implementation code in MainActivity that has to include those fragments, but when I set onTouch Listeners on fragments it gives me NullPointerException, however I do not know if its possible to add OnTouchListener to MainActivity itself?
Anyway, here's the code I wrote last time, it's giving me an error:

Attempt to write to field 'android.app.FragmentManagerImpl android.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object reference

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    private Fragment_1to6 f1to6;
    private Fragment_7to12 f7to12;
    private buttonsFragment mButtonsFragment;

    private FrameLayout relative1;
    private RelativeLayout relative2;

    float x1, x2;
    float y1, y2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        relative1 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
        relative2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_7to12);


        if (!isInTwoPaneMode()) {
            mButtonsFragment = (buttonsFragment) mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_buttons);
            FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment_1to6());
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();

            relative1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                            x1 = event.getX();
                            y1 = event.getY();
                            break;
                        }

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                            x2 = event.getX();
                            y2 = event.getY();

                            // right to left
                            if (x1 > x2) {
                                    changeToSecondFrag();

                                    mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();

                                return true;
                            } if (x1 < x2) {

                                    changeToFirstFrag();
                                    mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();

                                return true;

                            } break;

                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

        } else {
            mButtonsFragment = (buttonsFragment) mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_buttons);
            f1to6 = (Fragment_1to6) mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_1to6);


            f7to12 = (Fragment_7to12) mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_7to12);


        }

        }



    private boolean isInTwoPaneMode(){
    return findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) == null;
}

    public void changeToSecondFrag(){

            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, f7to12);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();

    } public void changeToFirstFrag(){

            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, f1to6);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();

    }


        }
```

Answer (score 2):

try to handle *MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE* istead of *ACTION_UP*.

Let's define a *swipe* action as "when user touches and moves finger more than some threshold distance".
So your handler could look like:

```
boolean mSwipePending = false; // let's introduce this flag field 

...

// inside touch listener
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
    x1 = event.getX();
    y1 = event.getY();
    mSwipePending = true;
    break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
    mSwipePending = false; // do not care about swipe, if up
    break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    if (mSwipePending) {
        if (event.getX() > x1 + threshold) {
            doSomethighWhenSwipeRight();
            mSwipePending = false; // stop next move handling
        } else if (event.get(X) < x1 - threshold) {
            doSomethighWhenSwipeLeft();
            mSwipePending = false; // stop next move handling
        }
    }
```

You can define *threshold* as some predefined value (e.g. 100), but better to calculate it thru screen density.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking to swipe two fragments why don't you try using a **ViewPager** and **FragmentPagerAdapter**.

Here, this tutorial will guide you how to add your fragments to a ViewPager to achieve that left and right swiping effect.

http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-fragmentpageradapter-example/

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want only 2nd and 3rd fragment to exchange places but the 1st one always remains in Activity. so I guess pager adapter is not suitable for this